# "whereis" and "which" return different paths in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, path, macports, which

I've got the default OpenSSL 9.8 (Mac OS X 10.6.8) and decided to install the newest version (1.0.1) via MacPorts (`sudo port install openssl`).

These are console output of **which** and **whereis** commands:

```
$ whereis openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

(this is default system's one)

```
$which openssl
/opt/local/bin/openssl
```

(this is installed via MacPorts)

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

(there is mac port's version in PATH)

Why are different paths returned for `whereis` and `which`, and is this okay? Is there any way to get equal results?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the manpage of `whereis`, it clearly says (emphasis mine):

> The whereis utility checks the **standard binary directories** for the specified programs, printing out the paths of any it finds.
>
> The path searched is the string returned by the sysctl(8) utility for the ``user.cs_path'' string

Contrary to that, `which` is the tool commonly used to check where a binary is for your user's path.

> The which utility takes a list of command names and searches the path for each executable file that would be run **had these commands actually been invoked**.

That explains your difference, since `/opt/local/bin` is not a system-wide "standard" path—after all, MacPorts is a completely optional installation—and `sysctl` only has `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` in its `user.cs_path` per default.

In general, stick to `which` or `which -a` to find a binary rather than using `whereis`.

---

You can theoretically change `user.cs_path` through

```
sysctl -w user.cs_path=/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

but I don't know if that is such a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, you've highlited that "The whereis utility checks **the standard binary directories**" - that is the answer!
_couldn't vote up for you answer cause of small reputation((_

Comment: Don't worry, you'll surely get more reputation soon. Welcome to Super User! :)

Comment: Have the same problem with psql on OS X - unfortunately user.cs_path is not writable. Getting closer to my solution though, thanks for such a useful answer!